# Questions with s.endswith - python3.4

Tags: python, string

please tell me why my code didn't work the way I thought it would in python 3.4:

```
r = input("file address")
file = open(r)
for line in file:
    if line.endswith("d") is True:
        print(line)
```

my file is a *.txt and contains the following lines:

```
This line ends with a
this line ends with b
this line ends with c
this line ends with d
```

I expected python to print out the last one for it has the "d" at the end. However, the program did nothing.
When I change the boolean to "false", the python prints out all the lines. So I guess python sees the boolean "line.endswith("d") is False in its nature. How is that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lines contains newlines, so the conditional never evaluates to true.

You should either `s.strip()` the newline before calling `str.endswith()` or check for `s. endswith("d\n")`.

Comment: thanks! I'm marking this one as answer because of the suggestion to check for s.endswith("d\n").

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check `if line.endswith("d"):`, it will either evaluate to `True` or `False` you don't need to use `if line.endswith("d") is True` and use `line.strip().endswith("d")` to remove the `\n`.

The last char is a `"\n"` so `line.endswith("d")`  will never be `True`

Comment: Thanks! I apreicate you telling me about the unnecessary part of my code alot! I'm sorry I can only mark one as answer

Answer (score 1):

It does that because you're not stripping each line. You need to run `line = line.strip()` for each line which gets rid of the `\n` (backslash-n) which is what each line actually ends with. So your line: `This line ends with a this line ends with b this line ends with c this line ends with d` actually ends in `\n` (backslash-n) but you don't see it because python doesn't print it. (It prints a new line)!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct about the \n. Sorry, I can only mark one as answer